# pure function to change element in list

Tags: kotlin

I want function return new list with the new value without mutate the original list

```
fun <T> change(list:List<T>,index:Int,value:T){
  

}
```

examble in typescript

```
function change<T>(array:T[],index:number,value:T){
   return [...array.slice(0,index),value,...array.slice(index + 1)]
}
```

Comment: You want to return new list without changing the values of the original one

Answer (score 3):

A similar approach to your Type Script code would be:

```
fun <T> List<T>.with(element: T, atIndex: Int) =
    subList(0, atIndex) + element + subList(atIndex + 1, size)
```

or

```
fun <T> List<T>.with(element: T, atIndex: Int) =
    take(atIndex) + element + drop(atIndex + 1)
```

Usage:

```
val list = listOf(1,2,3,4,5)
println(list.with(10, atIndex = 2))
```

Note that this creates many temporary lists, which may be undesirable (I don't know if the TypeScript code also does that). If you don't want that, you can just create a mutable list, and add things to it (`subList` returns only a view of the list, and doesn't create anything new):

```
fun <T> List<T>.with(element: T, atIndex: Int) =
    ArrayList<T>(size).apply {
        addAll(this@with.subList(0, atIndex))
        add(element)
        addAll(this@with.subList(atIndex + 1, this@with.size))
    }
```

Or you can use the experimental API [`buildList`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/build-list.html)

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalStdlibApi::class)
fun <T> List<T>.with(element: T, atIndex: Int) =
    buildList(size) {
        addAll(this@with.subList(0, atIndex))
        add(element)
        addAll(this@with.subList(atIndex + 1, this@with.size))
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use persistent collections as @broot is suggesting, you can just use `mapIndexed` which is O(n):

```
fun <T> List<T>.change(index: Int, value: T): List<T> =
    mapIndexed { i, originalValue -> if (index == i) value else originalValue }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Sweeper answer, you can also consider using [persistent collections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure). If you need to perform such operations frequently, persistent collections could be much more performant approach both CPU- and memory-wise, by avoiding the data copying. In simple words, they create a new collection by keeping a reference to the original one and "remembering" the modification to apply it on the fly.

There is at least one implementation of persistent collections for Kotlin, provided by the Kotlin team themselves: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.collections.immutable . You can use it like this:

```
val list1 = persistentListOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val list2 = list1.set(2, 8)

println(list1) // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
println(list2) // [1, 2, 8, 4, 5]
```